# AES-256-GCM using lua

Tags: encryption, lua, openssl

I need to find a way to use the cipher AES-256-GCM with lua.
I installed the openssl module on lua but i dont understand how to use it to AES-256-GCM, how to get the authentication tag.

help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read the README.md file in the github repo

> https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-nettle

```lua
  local aes256 = aes.new("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest", "gcm", "testtesttest", "testtesttesttest1asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd")
  local ciphertext, digest = aes256:encrypt("a")
  print("aes256 gcm enc", #ciphertext, hex(ciphertext))
  print("aes256 gcm dgst", #digest, hex(digest))
  local aes256 = aes.new("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest", "gcm", "testtesttest", "testtesttesttest1asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd")
  local plaintext, digest = aes256:decrypt(ciphertext)
  print("aes256 gcm dec", #plaintext, plaintext)
  print("aes256 gcm dgst", #digest, hex(digest))
```

the result should be like this:

```lua
aes256 gcm enc  1   3B
aes256 gcm dgst 16  EFB12AF268F64A602779EAE2F8C2FA03
aes256 gcm dec  1   a
aes256 gcm dgst 16  EFB12AF268F64A602779EAE2F8C2FA03
```